# After updating phpunit to version 3.6.3, assertRedirectTo() fails

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit

Before updating phpunit everything was ok, function `assertRedirectTo()` worked as it should, but after updating it shows this error:

> Declaration of `Zend_Test_PHPUnit_Constraint_Redirect::evaluate()` should be compatible with that of `PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint::evaluate()`

Can anybody explain what exactly happened?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, I ran into this problem too two days ago. But on the unfortunetly Zend Framework 1.x is not going to support PHPunit 3.6 or higher :-(

So the best thing is that you go back to 3.5 which is the latest version Zend Framework supports.

Check this:

http://zendframework.com/issues/browse/ZF-11871

Here you can read they will proberly make ZF2 supporting 3.6:
http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Running-the-zend-unit-tests-with-the-phpunit-3-6-PHP-CodeCoverage-Filter-getInstance-problem-td4023996.html